# BlackBerry RichTextField change font

Tags: blackberry, richtext

I would like to change the font of a RichTextField but I want to change it after the initialization of the Field.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Font font = Font.getDefault() ;
FontFamily ff;
try 
{
    ff = FontFamily.forName("arial");
    font = ff.getFont(FontFamily.SCALABLE_FONT, 18).derive(Font.BOLD);
    field.setFont(font);
} 
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) 
{

}
```

Comment: Hi,
First thank you for your reply, it doesn't work, actually I created an ObjectChoiceField and I want the user to select font size and then to apply it on the RichTextField, what you gave me works only on the ObjectChoiceField, My richtextfield is being created in another class and I make it static

Answer (score 1):

If you can obtain the reference to the RichTextField, you can call `setFont(Font font)` on it, and then call `invalidate()` to force the field to repaint itself. `invalidate()` is a protected method, so you're going to have to modify your RichTextField class (extend it) to either update `setFon`t to automatically call `invalidate`, or provide a public version of `invalidate` that you can call.

Answer (score 0):

other way...

```
try {
            myFontFamily = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Serif");
            Font appFont = myFontFamily.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 6, Ui.UNITS_pt);
            field.setFont(appFont );

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```